# Does a person become kafir for having doubts about the existence of Allah S.W.T?

Tags: doubts

I heard that one who has doubts about Allah S.W.T will burn in hell. Is that true ? Does yakeen or strong conviction means a person has no doubts about Allah S.W.T at all. Please make this clear. Please tell me does a person becomes kafir for having doubts about the existence of Allah.? Allah S.W.T says :
The (true) believers are those only who believe in Allah and His messenger and afterward doubt not, but strive with their wealth and their lives for the cause of Allah. Such are the sincere.Quran (49:15). 
So does someone who doubt the existence of God becomes kafir ?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Having doubts about Allah or Islam does *not* make one a kafir, whose meaning derives from "to cover". So a "kafir" would be, *not* one who doubts or uses his/her mind in considering the issue of faith and a supreme power, but rather one who seeks actively to *cover* the truth. Also this would apply to those who actively try to *suppress* the truth. One of the greatest sins in the Quran is oppression, and also repression, of truth. Also, the Quran frequently enjoins people to "use their minds" -- an expression in English that gives the right impression of the Arabic, except that the Quran refers to the mind not as a noun but only as a verb, to think, but I the Quran thinking is done in the "heart", which again as in English means the "core" of a person, his free will understanding.

It goes beyond the parochial idea some have about Islam, that its adherents worship the Prophet Mohammad, which would be considered idolatry and kufr ... because worship of any created being or thing is a form of denial of Allah. This is actually a profound concept but many refuse to use their minds to deepen their understanding of it.  But the word *worship* should not be confused with honor or even *sacred*. Life is sacred, but not something to "worship" per se. So we *honor* Prophet Mohammad but do not worship him.

So what then is the case of the doubter? If the doubt occurs in the process of free thought, considering the idea of God/ Allah — and it is a very abstract yet real idea, which is important! — and as long as the idea is "in play" and not settled on and decided on and kept as your internal guiding dogma, then you are in a state of flux, one could say, but not kufr. Once however you settle on that doubt as your faith and your creed, that by which you guide your actions, then that would make you in a situation of "covering up" the truth, not seeking it, and deceiving yourself as having arrived at some conclusion.

To a disbeliever, denial of Allah's existence is an article of faith. But it seems strange to those who base their logic on no God and also (comes with the territory) an essential meaninglessness to existence or randomness, that one would think of God as truth and denial of God as deceit. Muslims on the other hand think it strange that one would see the heavens and the earth and other signs in mathematics and in their own consciousness, and then base their reality on "nothing matters" and nothing has any intrinsic meaning or value, and there is no unifying principle, but further, no essential goodness, no Creator, no supreme Power to whom we all return. The nature of the Islamic faith unlike Christianity as it is mostly practiced today is that Islam does not oppose logic. There is no logical argument *against* he existence of God, who is also beyond proof, insofar as proof is a type of "control" and Allah cannot be, as supreme power, controlled because God alone is in complete control.

Just note that the depth of this reality, the existence and dynamic always living presence of God/ Allah is beyond what you can "wrap your head around." It's a decision. Deciding to consider Allah as Almighty, All-Merciful and to be worshipped then opens up a door, an entrance (fatiha) into an understanding of how our lives are deeply meaningful and what we do matters more than we can imagine, and there are consequences after this life. Considering this possibility as true for a moment, feeling the weight of it and its depth, that is the flip side of doubt. You need to consider both sides to determine if you will surrender your ego to Allah or live for this life and for yourself, guided by your ego and desires, enjoying the temporary feeling that comes with thinking that nothing really matters. But that too has consequences.

All the warnings in the Quran are ultimately in your own interest and not a sort of in-club membership denial. It is good to take such matters seriously as I believe you do.

Comment: We have some answers to questions here in Islam.SE that also explain this point of view of what kafir means, you could quote that too in order to make the answer less broad

Answer (score 2):

Whoever doubts Allah or anything else that Allah has said in the Quran or anything the Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) has said has disbelieved. Allah said in Surah Al Hujurat (49:15):

إِنَّمَا الْمُؤْمِنُونَ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا بِاللَّهِ وَرَسُولِهِ ثُمَّ لَمْ يَرْتَابُوا وَجَاهَدُوا بِأَمْوَالِهِمْ وَأَنْفُسِهِمْ فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ أُولَئِكَ هُمُ الصَّادِقُونَ

"The believers are only the ones who have believed in Allah and His Messenger and then doubt not but strive with their properties and their lives in the cause of Allah. It is those who are the truthful."

An example of someone who doubted whether or not he would be resurrected is in Surah Al Kahf (18:35-37). Allah says:

وَدَخَلَ جَنَّتَهُ وَهُوَ ظَالِمٌ لِّنَفْسِهِ قَالَ مَا أَظُنُّ أَن تَبِيدَ هَٰذِهِ أَبَدًا (35) وَمَا أَظُنُّ السَّاعَةَ قَائِمَةً وَلَئِن رُّدِدتُّ إِلَىٰ رَبِّي لَأَجِدَنَّ خَيْرًا مِّنْهَا مُنقَلَبًا (36) قَالَ لَهُ صَاحِبُهُ وَهُوَ يُحَاوِرُهُ أَكَفَرْتَ بِالَّذِي خَلَقَكَ مِن تُرَابٍ ثُمَّ مِن نُّطْفَةٍ ثُمَّ سَوَّاكَ رَجُلًا (37)

"And he entered his garden while he was unjust to himself. He said, "I do not think that this will perish - ever.
(35) And I do not think the Hour will occur. And even if I should be brought back to my Lord, I will surely find better than this as a return."
(36) His companion said to him while he was conversing with him, "Have you disbelieved in He who created you from dust and then from a sperm-drop and then proportioned you [as] a man? (37)"

Here, the man did not say he was sure the Hour would not occur. Rather, he doubted its occurrence, and this caused him to enter disbelief, as his companion states.

The misguidance and the bad ending of the one who doubts is affirmed in the following hadith, which is recorded in ibn Majah. (https://sunnah.com/urn/1344080)

The Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) said:

وَيُجْلَسُ الرَّجُلُ السُّوءُ فِي قَبْرِهِ، فَزِعًا مَشْعُوفًا، فَيُقَالُ لَهُ: فِيمَ كُنْتَ؟ فَيَقُولُ: لَا أَدْرِي، فَيُقَالُ لَهُ: مَا هَذَا الرَّجُلُ؟ فَيَقُولُ: سَمِعْتُ النَّاسَ يَقُولُونَ قَوْلًا، فَقُلْتُهُ، فَيُفْرَجُ لَهُ قِبَلَ الْجَنَّةِ، فَيَنْظُرُ إِلَى زَهْرَتِهَا وَمَا فِيهَا، فَيُقَالُ لَهُ: انْظُرْ إِلَى مَا صَرَفَ اللَّهُ عَنْكَ ، ثُمَّ يُفْرَجُ لَهُ فُرْجَةٌ قِبَلَ النَّارِ، فَيَنْظُرُ إِلَيْهَا، يَحْطِمُ بَعْضُهَا بَعْضًا، فَيُقَالُ لَهُ: هَذَا مَقْعَدُكَ ، عَلَى الشَّكِّ كُنْتَ، وَعَلَيْهِ مُتَّ، وَعَلَيْهِ تُبْعَثُ، إِنْ شَاءَ اللَّهُ تَعَالَى

"And the evil man is made to sit up in his grave with fear and panic. It is said to him: ‘In what [condition] were you?’ He says: ‘I do not know.’ It is said to him: ‘Who is this man?’ He says: ‘I heard the people saying something and I said it too.’ Then a window to Paradise is opened to him, and he looks at its beauty and what it contains. It is said to him: ‘Look at what Allah has diverted from you.’ Then a window to Hell is opened for him, and he sees it, parts of it destroying others, and it is said to him: ‘This is your place. You were doubtful; in this state you died and in this state you will be resurrected, if Allah, may He be exalted, wills.’"

It's important to note that there's a difference between something crossing your mind and you actually being unsure and doubting. If something crosses your mind, it is there for a short time, and it leaves, and you do not believe it. A true doubt is when an individual is unsure, and truly does not believe 100%. This is what is blameworthy. As for something crossing your mind, Allah has forgiven this.

As reported in Sahih Bukhari (5269) (https://sunnah.com/bukhari/68/19), the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings be upon him) said:

إِنَّ اللَّهَ تَجَاوَزَ عَنْ أُمَّتِي مَا حَدَّثَتْ بِهِ أَنْفُسَهَا، مَا لَمْ تَعْمَلْ أَوْ تَتَكَلَّمْ

"Allah will forgive my ummah for whatever crosses their minds so long as they do not act upon it or speak of it."

If a person has doubts, they should take the means to quell these doubts, as there is clear evidence for the existence of Allah, the prophethood of Muhammad (peace and blessings upon him), and the religion of Islam. Because this has already been a long post, I will put just one proof, although there are many, of the existence of Allah.

Allah says in Surah At-Tur (52:33-36):

أَمْ خُلِقُوا مِنْ غَيْرِ شَيْءٍ أَمْ هُمُ الْخَالِقُونَ (35) أَمْ خَلَقُوا السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضَ ۚ بَل لَّا يُوقِنُونَ (36)

"Or were they created by nothing, or were they the creators [of themselves]?
(35) Or did they create the heavens and the earth? Rather, they are not certain. (36)"

May Allah guide us and the rest of the Muslims to the straight path and remove any doubts that enter our hearts.
And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

If you realize that your doubt is a sin and question it (Otherwise known as wiswas) then that means it is shaiytan and another devil whispering in your ear. You will be forgiven and if you repent as instructed by Allah.

I believe this link explains my answer with the most details and cites all it's sources: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/25778/disturbed-by-waswas-whispers-from-the-shaytan-and-evil-thoughts?fbclid=IwAR0V13ZoVTwlJPp9mPt4k-JMity-v63XNQ7CLkwzqa3yPDB0zizBCRU2heg

If you have doubt in such ways that you cannot identify that this is wiswas, to the point that you lead astray, then please seek information from a different link as the one above does not apply.

Answer (score -1):

it totally depeneds on your real intention, i have heard many people having these waswasas about allah and i have had them myslelf, but i have heard this is a sign for clear faith. here is a video adressing the issue

https://youtu.be/1O-EkMAnQlc

Answer (score -2):

Thoughts do not count, but rather your speech and actions.  Other than for  those who have achieved **yakeen** (closeness to Allah) and **ihlas** (purity of faith) it is normal to have doubting thoughts.

This is the test of sheytan, these waswasi thought whispers and doubts.  You must pass these tests in order to achieve yakeen and ihlas.  While the blessed few achieve yakeen and ihlas in relatively short time, for many Muslims this takes years and for some a lifetime.

So don't worry doubting thoughts don't make you kufur.  It's just sheytan at work.  If you are having the same doubting thoughts, it is a sign from Allah that you need help and advise from alim  (leaned people of Islam).
After more than 1400 years of history, there are no doubts that haven't been already addressed.  If you can point out what your specific doubts are as a separate question we can surely help you InshAllah.

Now if you made a conscious decision to reject Allah and his messenger and openly declare this in writing or orally in front of witnesses.  Then you will be kufur.

Comment: But dear what does this mean 
[ Allah will say], "Throw into Hell every obstinate disbeliever, preventer of good, aggressor, and doubter [Quran 50:24-25]

Comment: Again a having doubting thoughts does not make you a doubter.  It's only when you express your doubts as convictions of rejection of faith either through writing or speech to corrupt the faith of yourself and others.  There has to be an act of rejection, not just idle doubting thoughts.